# Asking for feedback, when utilizing Pandas, why is it better to use pandas.Series than lists data type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparative-review, pandas

I found out the hard way, when utilizing pandas is better to use `pandas.Series` than `lists` data type to manipulate data.
Even if I understood how pandas stores different data types, I did not realize the ramification of using `lists` of **strings** instead of `pandas.Series` of **objects**.

[Pandas dtype](https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html)

[image: Pandas dtype]

Like the pic above shows, pandas store **strings** as **objects**, it does not discriminate between **strings, lists, dictionaries and etc**, python [iterable](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module2_EssentialsOfPython/Iterables.html).
I made my own function that returns a `pandas.DataFrame` column names, columns' pandas dtypes and columns' python data types, see pic below.

[image]

Most `pandas.DataFrame`s that I encountered have a `NaN` values representing any values that are undefined.
A `pandas.DataFrame` column of *string objects*, first_names for example, can contain `NaN` values, `NaN` is a float data type.
The main reason that the `NaN` value is commonly utilize, it is due to its usefulness, when combine with a function like [`DataFrame.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), it becomes a well recognize and powerful tool for data manipulation.

Most pandas teaching materials utilize `lists` and `pandas.DataFrames` to manipulate data, so I did the same, see code below:

```
    # Removes Html code and \n
    for name in essay_names:
        # Initializes essay text list 
        essay_txts = []
        for essay in profiles[name]:
            # Checks if the essay is empty, NaN
            if type(essay) == type(.0):
                # Adds NaN text to the essay texts Series, empty text
                essay_txts.append(np.NaN)
            else:
                essay_clean = re.sub('', '', essay).replace('\n', ' ').replace('  ', ' ')    
                essay_txts.append(essay_clean)
        # Stores cleaned essay text 
        profiles[f'{name}_text'] = essay_txts
```

The code lines `essay_txts = []` and `essay_txts.append(np.NaN)` create issues when trying to manipulating the DataFrames data with `DataFrame.dropna()`, the `essay_txts` is a `list` of *strings*, the `np.nan` value was not saved in the `list` as a `float` but as *string*, `'nan'`, and by consequence it was also saved in the `DataFrame` as a *string*.
The `DataFrame.dropna()` function will not recognize the value as `NaN float` and it will not drop the `DataFrame` row where the values was inputted.

Replacing the code lines
`essay_txts = []`
`essay_txts.append(np.NaN)`
with
`essay_txts = pd.Series(dtype='object')`
`essay_txts = essay_txts.append(pd.Series(np.NaN), ignore_index=True)`
is my solution to the issues created by using `lists` and trying to utilize the `NaN` value to manipulate data with pandas.

See full code below

```
    # Removes Html code and \n
    for name in essay_names:
        # I use pandas Series, a Series will accept NaN float and object (string) values
        essay_txts = pd.Series(dtype='object')
        for essay in profiles[name]:
            # Checks if the essay is empty, NaN
            if type(essay) == type(.0):
                # Adds NaN text to the essay texts Series, empty text
                essay_txts = essay_txts.append(pd.Series(np.NaN), ignore_index=True)
            else:
                essay_clean = re.sub('', '', essay).replace('\n', ' ').replace('  ', ' ')
                essay_txts = essay_txts.append(pd.Series(essay_clean), ignore_index=True)
        # Stores cleaned essay text 
        profiles[f'{name}_text'] = essay_txts
```

Thank you for feedback, or for sharing a better way to address the issues created by using `lists` and trying to utilize the `NaN` value to manipulate data with pandas.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, from your question it seems me you are proposing two distinct solutions to the same problem asking for comparison. If this is the scenario, you can add the `comparative-review` tag to your question.